# PHP File Upload Error Line 17

Tags: php, file, file-upload, upload

I wrote a script that would allow me to upload images and files to my servers, and now that I've switched domains, everything seems a bit messed up.
I've changed the urls and directories, and I've got my chmod set at 777 for the directories needed (cdn and img)

Script:

```
$folder = "/cdn/img";
$HTTP_POST_FILES = "";
if(isset($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'])) {
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']))  {

    $ext = strtolower(end(explode('.', $_FILES['filename']['name'])));

    $fileCode = fileCode($ext);

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], $folder . $fileCode)) {
            echo 'Your file has been uploaded! View and share your file <a href="http://www.codyleek.me/' . $folder . '/' . $fileCode . '">here</a>';
    } else {
            echo "THERE'S A GLITCH IN THE MATRIX! YOUR FILE COULDN'T BE UPLOADED!";
    }
} else {
        Echo "Failed. Try again.";
}
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move '/tmp/phpZ1TbaL' to 'http://codyleek.me/cdn/img/e6fmd6.png' in /home/codyleek/public_html/cdn/upload.php on line 17
```

Sorry that my formatting sucks. I'm new here aha.
But um, could any of you help me? I've tried redoing the URLs, resetting permissions, everything I can think of.
My PHP knowledge is limited.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably want your `$folder` to point to a folder on the local file system.

Comment: That URL is on the local system. I tried a direct path because /cdn/img, cdn/img/ and cdn/img weren't working. Well, the URL wasn't working either, so I suppose I should change it.

Comment: What is the complete path of the `img` directory, relative to the root of the file system? That is probably the directory where you changed the permissions and that is the path you need to use.

Comment: `/home/username/public_html/cdn/img`
oh and cdn is also a subdomain, if that helps or affects anything.

Comment: No, subdomains don't have anything to do with this, just the local fiel system.

Comment: Ah, alright. Well, it's `/home/username/public_html/cdn/img`.

Comment: By the way, I normally don't set 777 permissions on folders, I just change the group to the user the web-server is using and give the group write permissions (775).

Comment: Better not change it in your question as then it does not make sense anymore as a question for future visitors.

Comment: Ah, yeah. I'll revert it back aha.

Comment: Derp, new problem. URL now. http://www.codyleek.me//home/username/public_html/cdn/img/e8ci8m.jpg

Comment: Have a `$docroot = '/home/username/public_html'; $folder = '/cdn/img/';` And use both in your `move_uploaded_file` and only $folder in building the `<a href=`

Comment: I fixed it by changing the URL it echoes out to. Thanks again, guys! :)

Answer (score 1):

You should move it to a path on your disk (for example `/srv/www/mydomain.com/img/test.png`) and not to another website like you're doing now (`http://...`). By using `http://x` you are saying: 'use the HTTP-protocol, on domain x to ....'

Comment: That URL is on the local system. I tried a direct path because /cdn/img, cdn/img/ and cdn/img weren't working. Well, the URL wasn't working either, so I suppose I should change it.